# Infer props from a functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to construct a tabbed table but I want to have the option of changing the type of table in each tab. I want to create a type where I can infer the required props the `Table` prop I pass in. I know I can do this with a generic but is it possible to do without a generic and infer the type from the Table arg?

Here is my current type:

```
export type Tab<TableProps = any> = {
  Table: FunctionComponent<TableProps>;
  name: string;
  label: string;
} & TableProps;
```

The ideal solution:

```
const tab: Tab = {
   Table: ListTable,
   name: 'foo',
   label: 'bar'
   columns: [],  // <- required props of ListTable inferred from Table
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example with jsx and expected infered type.

Comment: Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-frost-u09tzk?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: In order to infer a type during component call you should provide extra generic. For example: `const Component = <Infered,>({name}:Props<Infered>)=><div></div>`

Comment: @captain-yossarian could you explain this answer further? I'd be very interested finding a solution here.

Comment: See [small example](https://tsplay.dev/WvER3m)

Comment: Can this work to infer the props of a react component though?